# Interactive Sorting in a paginated row group Tablix with Chart

Tags: reporting-services

I have simplified my problem as follows:

1. A tablix with 2 columns dataset: Code (a, b, c, ...), and Value (random < 100).
2. Make a paginating group of 5 rows from the detail, steps [here](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/9/11/displaying-fixed-number-of-rows-per-ssrs-report-page.html).
3. Add an additional row inside the group, merge all columns, put rectangle to hold a Chart pointing to the same dataset. This is Chart1.
4. Add another row outside the group, to hold another copy of the exact Chart above. This is to later help the interactive sorting to work on the details beyond the boundary of the groups. This is Chart2. The final design will appear like this:

[image]

5. Create an interactive sorting for the column Code following this:

[image]

6. The final work shall look like this, where you can navigate the pages, while also have the 'sliding window' effect for viewing the chart, that is: Page 1 is a-e, Page 2 is f-j, etc.. Note that the interactive sort is also honored.

[image]

For simplicity, please download my RDL [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9UraboQ3EFObHNUSnJpRmUzdEE/view?usp=sharing).

Now, my problem: I have to make Chart1 to be on top of the Tablix1.

Doing so will make the column header of Tablix1 to be sandwiched between the Chart1 and the details. This will make the Interactive Sort to behave incorrectly, that each page have its own state of Interactive Sorting. How to solve this? Modified RDL [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9UraboQ3EFON0wwc2kzNmJsd2M/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2baa1c0f-d23e-4cbe-b8f5-5379a7ba0846/forum-faq-how-do-i-set-interactive-sort-across-multiple-groups-in-ssrs-2005?forum=sqlreportingservices) solves the question by doing a self referencing Drill Trough by the click of a cell or image. The Action will pass the parameter to toggle between Ascending and Descending sorting order of the Tablix.

Combining the above the solution with [this other link](http://blog.stevienova.com/2012/04/27/dynamic-sorting-using-parameters-in-ssrs/), we can keep the number of tablix stays to one, regardless of the number of columns to sort.

Get the final RDL [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9UraboQ3EFOUHBiQ2hua1p5XzQ/view?usp=sharing).